# Populating two sgrids faster

Tags: vb6, grid, vbaccelerator

I have about 10K records each that i have to populate in two vbaccelerators sgrids, i currently use the following code

```
With grdList
     .Clear
     If colTasks Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     .ReDraw = False
     For i = 1 To colTasks.Count
      AddItem colTasks(i)
    Next
  .ReDraw = True
End With
```

The additem subroutine is different for the two grids, peculiar to the data being pupulates. it looks like this

```
    Dim lCol   As Long
    Dim bIsDue As Boolean
    Dim sCat   As String
   sCat = cboCat.Text
   With grdList
       If IsEqual(sCat, oItem.Category) Or IsEqual(sCat, "all") Then
            ' Show/Remove Completed
           If Not IsNullOrEmpty(oItem.DueDate) Then
               sCat = DateDiff("d", oItem.DueDate, DateValue(Now))
               bIsDue = (CLng(sCat) > 0)
               If ShowDueOnly And Not bIsDue Then Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
      If lRow > .Rows Or lRow = 0 Then
          grdList.AddRow
          lRow = .Rows
        End If
        If Not IsNullOrEmpty(oItem.DueDate) Then
            lCol = .ColumnIndex("DueDate")
          lColor = IIf(bIsDue, vbRed, vbBlack)
          sCat = Format$(oItem.DueDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")
          .CellDetails lRow, lCol, CDate(sCat), DT_LEFT, IconIndex("ARROW"), , lColor
        End If
      lCol = .ColumnIndex("Privacy")
      .CellIcon(lRow, lCol) = IIf(oItem.IsPrivate, IconIndex("LOCK"), -1)
      'completed
      lCol = .ColumnIndex("Complete")
     .CellIcon(lRow, lCol) = IIf(oItem.Completed, IconIndex("CHECK"), -1)         
    End With
```

it takes about 20 seconds to fill the grids, is there anyway i can make this faster

Comment: Generally, in UI code, what slows things down the most is refreshing/repainting the control after each change. One easy way to determine if that's the problem here is to hide the control (set its `Visible` property) before you begin modifying its contents, then make it visible again after you're done.

Comment: yea, i did that. and you can also see that i even set `.ReDraw = False` to make things faster still. but i still think 20sec is too long to pupulate 20K items

Comment: don't add a row each time, but create enough rows from the start at once, and then fill those rows with the data

Comment: @Hrqls thanks for your tip, but i have to add rows conditionally, not all data will be added to the rows.

Comment: first build your data in a string array, using the required conditions. when that is done, make sure the grid has enough rows at once, and fill the grid with the data from the string array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for sGrid](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/S_Grid_2/S_Grid_2/article.asp) says "If you can add rows in order, you can choose to have SGrid pre-allocate a number of rows for you, rather than adding each one individually, which can improve performance. To do this, set the Rows property to the number of rows that you want."

Comment: thanks for your tip, but i have to add rows conditionally, not all data will be added to the rows.

Comment: I suspect you will find it's faster to iterate once through your loop just counting rows without doing anything, then create that many rows, then run through the loop populating the rows. It's worth experimenting!

Comment: i did create all the rows first, then i just remove the  ones after populating. thanks